# Group by ranges in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with `PRICE` and `ITEMS_COUNT` and the table looks like this:

```
price  items_count
-----  -----------
1.50       10
2.25       11
4.13       20
 ..        ..
```

Is there a way to build a query that shows me all the items in a fixed range?
I.e. something like this

```
range_price  range_items_count
-----------  -----------------
1.00 - 1.50         0
1.50 - 2.00         10
2.00 - 2.50         11
2.50 - 3.00         0
    ...            ...
```

The first solution I saw would be to actually specify each and every range, but I have a lot of entries and I would end up writing down 20, 30 rows of `CASE`s just to have what I need.

Is there a faster way? Thanks!

Edit: for each range, the min value is inclusive and the max value is exclusive and I don't really need to have the ranges where the value is 0.

Comment: do you using MySQL or MariaDB ?

Comment: is the range_Price always .50 and what is the lower and upper limits? or should these be parameters that you can specify?

Comment: @BerndBuffen I'm using MySQL

Comment: @xQbert it can be always .50 and I can have fixed lower and upper limits

Comment: So, `1.50` belongs to first group or to second group in your output example ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the ranges by "halves", you can do:

```
select floor(price * 2) / 2 as price_low, sum(items_count)
from t
group by floor(price * 2) / 2;
```

Actually getting the range requires some formatting:

```
select concat_ws(' - ',
                 cast(floor(price * 2) / 2 as decimal(5, 2)),
                 cast(0.5 + floor(price * 2) / 2 as decimal(5, 2))
                )  as price_range, sum(items_count)
from t
group by floor(price * 2) / 2;
```

That solves most of your problems.  Getting the counts of "0" is a big issue.  You need a list of all the ranges you want in the output to get the "missing" rows.